# backbone append to el cascades event

Tags: backbone.js

I have the following backbone code in my view (not full code):

```
render: function(){
    _.each(this.model_admin.getModelPool(), function(model){
        $("#anydata").append("<div class='row list-entry'></div>");
        view = new App.Views.ListItemView({el: $(".list-entry").last(), model: model, admin: this.admin})
        view.render();
    });
},

App.Views.ListItemView = Backbone.View.extend({
template: JST["listEntry"],

events: {
    "click .list-val" : "showModel"
},

initialize: function(options){
    this.el = options.el;
    this.model = options.model;
    this.admin = options.admin;
},

render: function(){
    $(this.el).html(this.template({name: this.model.modelName}))
},
```

Intention is to create a list of ListItemView. In the ListItemView, there is a "click .list-entry" event.

It would be easier if I pass "#anydata" to ListItemView as el. Then put the append on ListItemView instead of html(). However, it duplicates my event. Any better way to do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Things tend to work better when you let your views completely own their `el`s; this is the usual way of doing things with Backbone and it helps avoid strange event problems and some types of zombie.

Your `render` should look more like this:

```
render: function() {
    _.each(this.model_admin.getModelPool(), function(model) {
        var view = new App.Views.ListItemView({ model: model, admin: this.admin });
        $('#anydata').append(view.render().el);
    });
    return this; // This is standard practice.
}
```

The above would be even better if `#anydata` was that view's `el`.

Then you can let the `ListItemView` create the `<div class="row list-entry">` as its `el`:

```
App.Views.ListItemView = Backbone.View.extend({
    className: 'row list-entry',

    template: JST["listEntry"],

    events: {
        "click .list-val" : "showModel"
    },

    initialize: function(options) {
        this.admin = options.admin;
    },

    render: function() {
        this.$el.html(this.template({ name: this.model.modelName }));
        return this; // Again, standard practice so that you can look at v.render().el
    },

    //...
```

Note that the [view constructor](http://backbonejs.org/#View-constructor) will automatically pull a few things out of `options` and make them properties of the view:

> **constructor / initialize** `new View([options])`
>   [...]
>   There are several special options that, if passed, will be attached directly to the view: `model`, `collection`, `el`, `id`, `className`, `tagName` and `attributes`.

so I've trimmed down your `initialize`. Also note that views already have a cached version of `$(this.el)` in [`this.$el`](http://backbonejs.org/#View-%24el). You can have a look at the [`el` documentation](http://backbonejs.org/#View-el) to see how `className` is used.

Comment: awesome! very concise explanation. just what I needed. Thanks!